# Can't import passwords to Chrome from Firefox 23

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I've tried doing the passwords import several times in Chrome 29.0.1547.66 (latest) from Firefox 23.0.1, but every time it simply doesn't import them.

Is this a Chrome bug or do I need to do something to Firefox to facilitate the smooth import of the passwords?

Comment: Just to confirm you are exporting the passwords in Firefox right?

Comment: I'm running an import from within Chrome to get the passwords from Firefox, if that is what you mean.

Comment: I can't believe that this wouldn't scare you away from storing passwords! Firefox's password storage is super insecure, I don't expect Chrome to be much better (Firefox is essentially clear text). It doesn't address the question per se, but I certainly would not store passwords in a browser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "solution" to this was to install LastPass on Chrome and Firefox, import to LastPass from Firefox, then just use the LastPass extension on Chrome.

Seems to be more secure this way as well.

Answer (score 0):

This was working for me

1. In Firefox install addon **Password Exporter** > export data to xml
2. Then install **Firefox 25.0.1** - FF will be downgraded to this old version (alternatively you can do this on another computer or in virtual computer)
3. You have to install the addon Password Exporter again > import data
4. In Chrome go to Menu > Bookmarks & Settings and import from Firefox